# Get an list of datas and store in array in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a struture of html like below,This is what there will be list of option

```
<div class='col-sm-4'>
        <div id='selectiondata' class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <h2 class='headerText'>Selections</h2>
                <p style="font-size: 14px;">Select only that apply to you.</p>
                <ul>
                    <li id="item1" data-cat="fruits">Banana</li>
                    <li id="item2" data-cat="fruits">Pineapple</li>
                    <li id="item3" data-cat="fruits">Oragne</li>
                    <li id="item4" data-cat="fruits">MAngo</li>   
                    <li id="item5" data-cat="Vegetables">Beans</li>
                    <li id="item6" data-cat="fruits">jackfruit</li>
                    <li id="item7" data-cat="Vegetables">carrot</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

From above div when user clicks it moves to adjacent div,this has a sturcture like below.

```
 <div id="categories" class="panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="alert alert-info hidden endMsg">Your data categorized. Once done, click the next button to continue.</div>
                    <h2 class='headerText'>Categories</h2>
                    <ul>
                        <li id="cat-fruits">
                            <span>fruits</span>
                            <ul>
                                <li id="item5" data-cat="fruits">MAngo</li>
                                <li id="item1" data-cat="fruits">Banana</li>
                                <li id="item3" data-cat="fruits">Oragne</li>
                                <li class="no-expenses" style="display: none;">No items selected</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li id="cat-Vegetables">
                            <span>Vegetables</span>
                            <ul>
                                <li id="item4" data-cat="Vegetables">Beans</li> 
                                <li class="no-expenses" style="display: none;">No items selected</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li id="cat-dolls">
                            <span>dolls</span>
                            <ul>
                                <li class="no-expenses">No items selected</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li id="cat-medical">
                            <span>Medical</span>
                            <ul>
                                <li class="no-expenses">No items selected</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
```

jquery function to fetch array of data

```
    function saveData() {
    userData = [];
    $('#categories ul li ul li.selected').each(function(index, element) {
        if ($.inArray($(this).text(), userData) < 0) {
            userData.push($(this).html());
        }
    });
```

I want to fetch datas like

```
 [MAngo,banana,Oragne,beans]
```

Here i will be having two divs,one div shows list of selection as shown in below figure, when user click on particular elemnet, that elemnet will be moved to next adjacent div(categories).I want to get this datas.

```
-----------   ----------
|Banana    |  | MAngo   |  
|Pineapple |  | Banana  |  
|Oragne    |  | Oragne  |  
|MAngo     |  | Beans   |  
|Beans     |  |_________|
|jackfruit |
|carrot    |
-----------
```

The above jquery used is not fetching any data from html, How could i acheive this. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would it be easier to add each item to the array when that item is clicked (and doesn't exist yet in the array)?

```
var arr = [];
$("#categories [id^=item]").click(function() {
   if(arr.indexOf($(this).html())<0) arr.push($(this).html());
})
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Please checck my updated question, i tried running your code, it gives all datas not selected one, and selected items are not in order.

Comment: @sany What should it give?

Comment: [MAngo,banana,Oragne,beans] because this is the user selected datas, which is find in div id="categories" ,

Comment: @sany My codes does give this. Click "Run code snippet" below my code.

Comment: this may give data if i have only one div with items, but i have two divs with items(one all items, other only user selected items) in same page, so how will it differentiate between two?

Comment: @sany Could you include the other div in your question?

Comment: Can you please explain me why  this used code was not fetching data $('#categories ul li ul li.selected').each(function(index, element){} as shown in question.

Comment: @sany Because the `<li>` can't be "selected". Only `<option>` can. Does my code work?

Comment: yes, instead of selectiondata  update with 'categories' because that is the div's item data i need. when i change to this i am getting correct data.

Comment: @sany "categories" is the original div? Ok. If my answer worked, please accept it by clicking the checkmark.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use data attr in @nicael code use

```
var arr = [];
$("#categories").data("cat").each(function() {
  arr.push($(this).html());
})
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr = [];

$('li[data-cat]').each(function() {
  arr.push($(this).html());
});

console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="categories" class="panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="alert alert-info hidden endMsg">Your data categorized. Once done, click the next button to continue.</div>
        <h2 class='headerText'>Categories</h2>
        <ul>
            <li id="cat-fruits">
                <span>fruits</span>
                <ul>
                    <li id="item1" data-cat="fruits">Mango</li>
                    <li id="item2" data-cat="fruits">Banana</li>
                    <li id="item3" data-cat="fruits">Oragne</li>
                    <li class="no-expenses" style="display: none;">No items selected</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="cat-Vegetables">
                <span>Vegetables</span>
                <ul>
                    <li id="item4" data-cat="Vegetables">Beans</li> 
                    <li class="no-expenses" style="display: none;">No items selected</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="cat-dolls">
                <span>dolls</span>
                <ul>
                    <li class="no-expenses">No items selected</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="cat-medical">
                <span>Medical</span>
                <ul>
                    <li class="no-expenses">No items selected</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```